# Algebraic extension of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $L/F/K$ is a tower of field extensions. Let $a\in L$. If $F/K$ is an algebraic extension of fields, is $F(a)/K(a)$ still an algebraic extension of fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $F(a)=K'(F)$ for $K' = K(a)$ and every element of $F$ is algebraic over $K$, so also over $K'$.